# ListView addHeaderView glitching around after onResuming Activity

Tags: android, android-listview

In my ListFragment I want a headerView to make the app look like its website counterpart.

onCreateView():

```
View headerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.header, null, false);
```

onStart():

```
if(headerView != null) {
    getListView().addHeaderView(headerView);
}
```

After pausing and resuming the activity, the headerView has a large top margin is glitching around: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q_zhr8w5Yzg

header.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/news_bubble"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/str_header"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Edit: This question is solved. If anybody stumbles upon this error, this is my code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
    listView = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    headerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.header, listView, false);
    listView.addHeaderView(headerView);
    [...]
    return rootView;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the list view as the container for your header view. So **inflate the listView first** and then inflate the header view as follows

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout,container,false);
    ListView listView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.my_list);
    View headerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.header, listView, false);
    listView.addHeaderView(headerView);
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Since I am using a ListFragment, `R.id.my_list` would be `android.R.id.list`, no?

Comment: Yep that worked. Thank you very much! Also, I didn't know I had to add the headerView in the onCreateView, so that could be a reason for the glitching too.